# Preventing single apostrophe colouring in np++ User Defined Language

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ User-Defined Language (UDL) you make syntax colouring for any language.

Now, I want to define a Delimiter Style for `'` single quotes so I can define it as a string.  The problem is that if the string has an apostrophe in it, the style gets disrupted.

```
Delimiter Style:
Open: '
Escape:
Close: '
```

The only thing I can think of is maybe to use Left single quotation mark (U+2018) and Right single quotation mark (U+2019) instead of Apostrophe (U+0027), but I can't figure out how to make that work in the UDL.

Actually, that wouldn't work either.  Who would ever type those U+ characters whilst coding, anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is to escape the single quote in the text.  It shouldn't be too hard to style the escaping.

For html, you'd have to use `&#39;` for your single quote.

```
Some 'text&#39;s string with apostrophe between single quotes'
```